# OpenVPN - high CPU even when cipher is set to none

Tags: openvpn

When sending 125mbit/sec over OpenVPN configured to use `cipher none`, the openvpn process uses 25% CPU (on an i3-5010U CPU).

What would cause it to use so much?

Here are the config files:

CLIENT.ovpn

```
remote xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
cipher none
auth none
dev tun
ifconfig 10.8.0.2 10.8.0.1
proto tcp-client
```

SERVER.ovpn

```
cipher none
auth none
dev tun
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
proto tcp-server
```

This is on Windows 10 in case it matters.

Comment: It is an older genertation slower clocked CPU, after all.

Comment: Agreed @MichaelHampton but we're only talking 16MBytes (125Mbit) of data per second - seems like 25% CPU usage is pretty high even for a less beefy CPU.  The CPU isn't terrible - has cpubenchmark.net rating of 3,057.  Does that utilization level seem in keeping with what you'd expect given this?